# How to create MVC5 web project in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just installed Visual Studio 2022 and I wanted to create a .Net Framework standard MVC5 web application project but, surprisingly, no option exists in the visual studio 2022 startup project template selection window for this type of project. I know Microsoft .Net core is new normal but it's completely removed from creating a new project? I have created the .Net Framework standard MVC5 project in Visual Studio 2019 but it seems it's removed in 2022. So is there any workaround to create this type of project in Visual Studio 2022?

Visual Studio 2019 Picture:
[image: Visual Studio 2019 Picture]

Visual Studio 2022 Picture:
[image: Visual Studio 2022 Picture]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to your VS2022 installer for `Individual Components` and select:

`.Net Framework project and item templates`

> Enables .NET Framework project templates, item templates & related features for .NET Framework development.

It adds ~ 1.6GB of data, which might be the reason for not being included by default in the first place during the Visual Studio 2022 install.

Answer (score 13):

Open Visual Studio Installer ->  select below highlighted option -> click on modify:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After installing .Net Framework project and item templates
I tried to create a new MVC project and I get HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from call to a COM Component

I can't see any log or better error to understand whats going on.
Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this options below Azure Development.

[image]

If still don't displaying, Repair the Visual Studio 2022.

[image]